# DOM doesn't load correctly but when I >>inspect element it refreshes and then loads correctly

Tags: html, dom, shopify

I'm building a shopify page and trying to add in the customer reviews app. I've included the snippet of code, but when the page loads, it looks like this:

[image: Reviews over the top of other content]

When I do >>inspect element in Safari or Chrome, the DOM reloads and it fixes itself. What do I need to do for it to load correctly the first time?

[image: Loads correctly after inspect element]

Comment: this is probably an async problem. Check if you can disable the async loading of the snippet and try again. You'll need to play hard with JS.

Comment: I am also facing same issue with pizzajs pie charts. Did you find any solution?. I disabled the async loading of my script even though its displaying the same. Waiting for strong solution for this.